# how to make a condition in the controller with laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

hello friends I have this problem ... I have the table awards, users_profile..where in awards I keep image, description and score
so in my controller what I want to do is the following ... that if the user has the necessary points to claim this prize then he claims it and if he does not have enough points then he would show an error message

```
public function reclamarpremios(Request $request)
{
    $vago_puntos = request('vago_puntos');
    $premioID = request('id');
    $puntaje = request('puntaje');
    $perfil_users_app_id = request('perfil_users_app_id');
    $us = UserAppPerfil::where('id',$perfil_users_app_id);
    $reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','=',$vago_puntos);
    if(!$reclamo->exists())
    {
        $us->decrement('vago_puntos',$puntaje);
        $reclamo->increment('veces_reclamado');
        return response()->json([$us,$reclamo,'message' => 'Felicidades has reclamado esta promocion, el equipo de vagos estara en contacto con tigo para obtorgarte tu premio'],200);

    }else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'No tienes los suficientes vagos puntos'],422);  
    }

}
```

this code works half, since for example if a user has 1000 points and a prize is worth 500 points then he does not exchange it (he sends me to the else)...and inside if what I want is that in certain fields add and subtract certain values, besides showing the message
this is my table in the MySQL database [image: my table on DB]

Comment: So, I don't get it: ' if a user has 1000 points and a prize is worth 500 points then he does not exchange it'. The user should be able to claims a prize if he has enough points, right? Is this the problem?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem

Comment: Why are you denying this: if( ! $reclamo->exists() ) {...} ? You're going to the else clause because of this

Comment: Also: what is the return value from $reclamo variable? I think you should check that. Make a dd($reclamo); and see what is returned

Comment: I put it like this (I'm testing), because if I leave it normal if ($ reclama-> count ()> 0) ... the code works the other way round (if a gift is worth 500 points and a user has 200 points then this can be redeem) so with if (! $ claim-> count ()> 0) solve that ... (I know that doing that is wrong)

Comment: what is relationship between users_profile and awards table??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

friends after trying many times so solve it

```
public function reclamarpremios(Request $request)
{
    $vago_puntos = request('vago_puntos');
    $premioID = request('id');
    $perfil_users_app_id = request('perfil_users_app_id');
    $us = UserAppPerfil::where('id',$perfil_users_app_id)->first();
    if($reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','<=',$us->vago_puntos)->first())
    {
        $us->decrement('vago_puntos',$reclamo->puntos);
        $us->increment('premios_ganados');
        $reclamo->increment('veces_reclamado');
        return response()->json([$reclamo,$us,'message'=>'Felicidades has reclamado esta promocion, el equipo de vagos estara en contacto con tigo para obtorgarte tu premio'],200);
    }else{
        return response()->json(['message'=>'No tienes los suficientes vagos puntos'],422);
    }

}
```

I only have a little doubt ... does this mean >= greater and equal and does this mean <= less and equal?....
the funny thing is that if I leave it like this >= ... it happens to me that although I thong 200 points and a prize is worth 500 I can claim it and if I have more than 500 then I can't do it and if I leave it <= then if it works with the logic that I want.....I don't know if someone can explain to me why that happens?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand the second condition (`->where('puntos','=',$vago_puntos)`) in this line:

```php
$reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->where('puntos','=',$vago_puntos);
```

The prize that the user want to redeem is the prize which has the `id` equals to the `$premioID`, no? If so, you don't need that condition.

```php
public function reclamarpremios(Request $request)
{
    $vago_puntos = request('vago_puntos');

    $premioID = request('id');  //The prize id
    $puntaje = request('puntaje');
    $perfil_users_app_id = request('perfil_users_app_id');
    $us = UserAppPerfil::where('id',$perfil_users_app_id)->first();

    //Get the prize the user wants to redeem:
    $reclamo = Premios::where('id',$premioID)->first();
    if ($reclamo != null) { // if the prize exists
        $requiredPoints = $reclamo->puntos; //The required amount of points for that prize
        $userPoints = $us->puntos; //The user available points
        if ($userPoints >= $requiredPoints) {
            // if the user has the required amount of points, can redeem the prize:
            $us->decrement('vago_puntos',$puntaje);
            $reclamo->increment('veces_reclamado');
            return response()->json([$us,$reclamo,'message' => 'Felicidades has reclamado esta promocion, el equipo de vagos estara en contacto con tigo para obtorgarte tu premio'],200);
        }
        else {
            return response()->json(['message'=>'No tienes los suficientes vagos puntos'],422);
        }
    }else{
           return response()->json(['message' => 'This prize is not available']);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: following your advice throw me this error `Property [vago_puntos] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

Comment: I solved the problem by adding a -> firsts (); in the queries ... but I still have the same error as in my previous code :( .. even if I have 100 points the user can claim a prize of 500 points